# How do I rebind a Boost.TypeErasure any<...> object

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use a `Boost.TypeErasure any<...>` object as a polymorphic function object.
However, I can't figure out how to rebind it (like I could with `std::function`).
The following example code doesn't compile.

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/callable.hpp>

using namespace boost::type_erasure;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

struct A { void operator()(int){} void operator()(double){} };
struct B { void operator()(int){} void operator()(double){} };

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   A a; B b;

   any < mpl::vector <
      callable<void(int)>,
      callable<void(double)>,
      copy_constructible<>
   >> x = a, y = b;

   x = y; // rebind x to b, doesn't compile

   return 0;
}
```

When compiled with clang-3.5 -std=c++11, I got this error

```
/opt/local/include/boost/type_erasure/any.hpp:1083:9: error: no matching member function for call to
'_boost_type_erasure_assign_impl'
_boost_type_erasure_assign_impl(
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Randomly adding `relaxed` to the `mpl::vector` [seems to make it work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/235837438aef1a0f) (if I understand you correctly). Hopefully someone else will be able to tell you why (if this were correct).

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Read the document again and looks like adding `relaxed` is the right answer: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/type_erasure/relaxed.html

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [usage documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/basic.html), emphasis on what `relaxed` enables:

> The main class in the library is any. An any can store objects that
>   meet whatever requirements we specify. These requirements are passed
>   to any as an MPL sequence.
>
> ```
> any<mpl::vector<copy_constructible<>, typeid_<>, relaxed> > x(10);
> int i = any_cast<int>(x); // i == 10
> ```
>
> `copy_constructible` is a builtin concept that allows us to copy and
>   destroy the object. `typeid_` provides run-time type information so
>   that we can use `any_cast`. `relaxed` enables various useful defaults.
>   **Without `relaxed`, `any` supports exactly what you specify *and
>   nothing else***. **In particular, it allows default construction and
>   assignment of `any`.**